# How to factory reset a Gingerbread device?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, factory-reset, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I found an old phone of mine while cleaning, and would like to donate it. I've googled how to do a factory reset on a gingerbread device, and all of them say the same thing: go to Settings -> Privacy, and then click the Factory Data Reset button under Personal Data. The problem is, I don't have that option. My Privacy settings only have Lock Screen (display message text), and Backup and Restore (Back up my settings and Automatic Restore.) I don't have a Personal Data section.

The phone does not have a SIM card installed, but does have a google account attached, plus a lot of apps with on-board data. I know I can disconnect the google account, but how can I wipe all the apps and reset the phone to "new"?

It's a rooted HTC Sensation, if it matters, and I think is running CyanogenMod. (Like I said, it's an old phone...)

Answer (score 1):

If it's running CyanogenMod then it likely has a custom recovery loaded on it already. Just boot into it, wipe data / factory reset and wipe internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be noted before factory resetting an android is that you still end up having the root access on your device. In that case, I would rather suggest you to (unroot) it first. Download the firmware and then flash it. This will remove the root access (unroot) and also remove any data on your phone.